# Is it possible to use same route for multiple modules

Tags: php, zend-framework2, php-5.5

I am using zf2 to create a web application. And I need to know if there is anyway to use same route for multiple modules when use it it gives me a only 1 of them. So is it in anyway possible to use the same route for multiple modules. Because in 1 of the modules I'll be keeping:

`add.phtml`
`edit.phtml`

and in the other:

`index.phtml`
`delete.phtml`

so any thoughts?

Comment: How do you mean "it it gives me a only 1 of them". ZF2 merges all route configs from the different modules into one configuration array. So yes this is possible.

Comment: It's not possible exactly the same. During merging of configs will be overridden. Or I didn't understand the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make **[a template map configuration](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#configuration)** in each module. 
So in module `One`:

```
'template_map' => array(
    'module/one/add'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/add.phtml',
    'module/one/edit' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/edit.phtml',
),
```

In module `Two`:

```
'template_map' => array(
    'module/two/index'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/index.phtml',
    'module/two/delete' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/delete.phtml',
),
```

In your controller **[you can set any view template](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#controllers-and-view-models)** inside your `ViewModel`. It doesn't matter in which module you keep them:

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel()
$viewModel->setTemplate('module/one/add');
```

or

```
$viewModel->setTemplate('module/one/edit');
```

or

```
$viewModel->setTemplate('module/two/index');
```

or

```
$viewModel->setTemplate('module/two/delete');
```